# How to transfer Retention cohort data from GA to Excel

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics

I am using GA add on for Sheets to transfer data from GA to Sheets.
I want to transfer user retention cohort data, but I am unable to figure out the right metrics and dimensions for the same.

I tried metric: ga:cohortRetentionRate
and dimension: ga:cohort, ga:cohortNthDay, and some others

But, I keep getting the error "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together" even though I checked on [dev tools](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) that they can be queried together.

Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to compose a cohort requests by using the [Request Composer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/) tool, in the Cohort Request tab.

Programmatically, to make use of these new dimensions and metrics you must construct a V4 cohort request: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#cohorts